# Consuming .NET web service in Oracle Forms

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, biztalk, oracleforms

I have a web service that i need to consume in Oracle Forms. The web service is SOAP based service and was generated using Microsoft Biztalk Server. The service accepts a complex xml message as its request and returns a similar xml message as response.
I want to consume this service from within my Oracle Forms Application (Forms version 10.1.2.0.2). I followed the guidelines and added its reference from WSDL, a few java classes were generated for me but this is where I lost it.
From the generated code, i see that i might have to create a vector which consists of the complete hierarchy of xml schema that is expected by the service. But i need some advice in how to do so.
Has anybody worked on similar services before? Please share your experience or any helpful resources.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does this example from OTN Forms page help?

http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/forms/htdocs/10gr2/howto/webservicefromforms/ws_10_1_3_from_forms.html

Regards